# Is credhub available with run.pivotal.io?

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev

If yes then what is the url/api to access it from run.pivotal.io 's trial account. 
Also can the features of credhub be tested using pcfdev?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ver 0.28.0 is the latest PCFDev available on [PivNet](http://network.pivotal.io)
It is PCF ver 1.11.x. Two versions older. This version does not support CredHub.

If I recall correctly, in ver 1.12 all internal properties are stored in CredHub. That said, PCFDev is not meant for production by any means. So, it may not support CredHub.

To test locally, you can spin up a credhub instance. And use that in your PCF app. To do that you will need VirtualBox and spin up a bosh-lite instance with CredHub. 
Take a look at this [article](https://ultimateguidetobosh.com/tutorials/bosh-lite-virtualbox/) on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

No, credhub is not supported for application developers on PWS at this time.